# Count the first x integers of a group of values

Tags: kdb

I want to get the count starting from 1, of the number of occurrences of Y until its subsequent value is N. A simple example table can be found below, I've added an additional column called expected output to highlight what I'm trying to achieve.

```
tab:([]x:`N`N`Y`N`N`Y`Y`Y`N`N`Y`Y`Y;expected_output:0 0 1 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2 3)
```

I have been playing around with the idea of trying to use cut (granted that I can find the correct indexes) I could split the table up, get the count of each list, then piece it all back together somehow e.g.

```
0 2 3 5 8 10 cut tab
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach using scan

```
q)update c:0{y*x+y}\x=`Y from tab
x expected_output c
-------------------
N 0               0
N 0               0
Y 1               1
N 0               0
N 0               0
Y 1               1
Y 2               2
Y 3               3
N 0               0
N 0               0
Y 1               1
Y 2               2
Y 3               3
```

Essentially a modified version of `sums` which resets the counter back to zero (using zero/false multiplication) whenever the next boolean is zero

Answer (score 4):

Approach without scan, not as neat as terry's but should be faster on larger tab.

```
q)update o:{a+r-maxs differ[x]*r:sums a:`Y=x}x from tab
x expected_output o
-------------------
N 0               0
N 0               0
Y 1               1
N 0               0
N 0               0
Y 1               1
Y 2               2
Y 3               3
N 0               0
N 0               0
Y 1               1
Y 2               2
Y 3               3
```